# Language signs and vector values

Tags: c++

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

bool CheckForDislike(vector<string> disliked, string slowo) {
int i = 0;
while (i < disliked.size()) {
    if (slowo == disliked[i]) {
        return true;    
    }
    i++;
}
return false;
}


int main() {
cout << "Enter a word: ";
vector<string> disliked(2);
disliked[0] = "Szpinak";
disliked[1] = "Brokuły";
string slowo = "a";
while (cin >> slowo) {
    if (CheckForDislike(disliked, slowo)) {
        cout << "Biip\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << slowo << '\n';
    }
}
}
```

Above code should print "Biip" when you enter a word that is in disliked vector. 
It doesn't work for words with signs like "ą","ł" basically special signs from my native language. The function returns 1 or true for them, so the problem has to be somewhere in conditional, but i cant see why.

Comment: C++ and unicode really don't get along.  You might want to get a unicode library like ICU

Comment: It is not a good idea to copy whole vector every time you check and you may consider to use `std::unordered_set` for better lookup time than linear search. If you do not care at least use `std::find()` instead of manual loop.

Comment: Ok thanks for answers, its just a test code for exercise from the book, i didnt plan exception handling, type safety or performance ;)

Comment: Then just read this https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/